# Slider full html css

Tags: html, css, screen, responsive, slide

I have following problem. I want to make a slider in html and css but i can not ensure that the image is reponsive compared to the size of the screen. Here is my html and css code:

Thank you.

```css
#slide
{
    position: relative;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 550px;
}
.sbackground
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;            
    padding: 0;
    width: 200%;
    transition: left 1s;
}
.sbackground li
{
    display: inline;
}
#slide:target .sbackground
{
    left: -100%;
}
.demi_circle1
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 45%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}
.demi_circle2
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: 96.5%;
    top: 45%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}
h1
{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide">
    <ul class="sbackground">
        <li><img src="https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/15/3/1523458445-bg2.jpg" alt="background1" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/15/3/1523458463-teste.jpg" alt="background2" /></li>
     </ul>
     <a href="#sbackground" class="demi_circle1"><</a>
     <a href="#slide" class="demi_circle2">></a>
</div>
```

slide: is the complete block.
sbackground: for slider images
demi_circle : allows to navigate from right to left or from left to right.

Comment: Do you want the image to cover the full width of the page ?

Comment: Yes I want the image to cover the full width. Thank you

Comment: Try giving `width: 100wh;` for `.sbackground`

Comment: The problem is that the second barkground salivates below now, as if there was not enough room for him to be side by side. And the image is not resized when I reduce the size of the browser.

Comment: So are you trying to do something like this??  https://jsfiddle.net/y208d0L4/1/

Comment: Problem solved ! I ended up resuming my code, if someone wants help for the same project he can send me a private message.